# twilio javascript client set from number , also how I can get the call sid after connect?

Tags: twilio

twilio javascript client set from number , Also how I can get the call sid after connect?

I tried to set the from Number in the call options like the next lines before connect and still the same issue in the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Twilio.Device.setup(token);

    var connection = null;

    $("#call").click(function () {

        var params = { "Phone": $('#Phone').val(), "from":$('#Phone').val() };

        connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);

        return false;
    });
});
```

-- and inside the server side code vbnet  when I am generating the token I added  the next code but this doesn't solve the from number issue

```
        Dim options As New CallOptions()

        options.Record = True

        options.From = model.FromNumber


        Dim cap = New TwilioCapability(_settings.AccountSID, _settings.AuthToken)

        cap.AllowClientOutgoing(_settings.ClientCallApplicationSID, options)
```

dim token = cap.GenerateToken()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

The [params collection](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device#connect-handler) that you pass into the connect function is just a dictionary of key/value pairs.  Those key/values simply get passed as parameters to the Voice URL that Twilio requests when Client makes its connection to Twilio, and  you can use those parameters to dynamically generate some TwiML markup.  Twilio does not do anything with them.

For example, if this is a PHP application, in the Voice URL you could do something like:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>$_REQUEST['From']</Dial>
</Response>
```

One note of caution, Twilio already adds a parameter called *from* (which [in the case of Client](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous-request-parameters) will be the client identifier set when you made your [capability token](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/capability-tokens#allow-incoming-connections)) to the parameters sent to the Voice URL, so you might want to choose a different key name for your dictionary entry.  I normally use a name like *target* for the key that holds the number that I want to dial.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Devin,
As i mentioned I set the parameter 'From' with a number that purchased from Twilio and when I checked Twilio logs I see the from number it is another number, i can't figure out if it is related for application we setup on twilio or where I should set the from number , thank you if you  can help

Comment: Again, creating a key/value pair with a 'from' key in the parameters your passing to Twilio client isn't going to automatically do anything for you.  You still have to generate the TwiML using <Dial> with the right from number to tell Twilio to connect your Client to that number.  The code that does that would be hosted at your TwiML apps Voice URL.  If you are dialing the wrong number it sounds like that app is not returning the right TwiML to Twilio.

Comment: just to be clear, you don't need to use the REST API's to accomplish what you want to do.  Feel free to email me offline if you need more help: devin [at] twilio [dot] com.

I'm happy to send you a sample project.

Answer (score 1):

To get the call sid, you can get it in connect event.

Please note that I am using Twilio JS v1.9.7

```
device.on('connect', function (conn) {
  log('Successfully established call!');

  //Get the CallSid for this call
  callUUID = conn.outboundConnectionId;
  console.log('CallSid: ' + callUUID);
});
```